# Fetching initial data for rendering components in React

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a website in Isomorphic React. I am fetching data from inside the constructor method. But data doesn't show up.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    /**
     * @type {object}
     * @property {array} tracks all tracks
     */

    const data = fetchDemoData();

    this.state = {
      name:data
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [react docs on loading initial data via Ajax](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) you should fetch initial data in the `componentDidMount` method.

So you set the initial state in the constructor, and update it in componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change state with `this.state` mutation. This goes against react fundamental principal to change state **only** with `this.setState()`. If you need to get default state for your component you should use `static initialState` (in case you're using `class` based components) or `getInitialState()` (in case you're using `React.createClass`).

Common practice for backend rendering is too avoid using state at all. Instead use props. Consider 2 components:

```
class FooContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Foo
        users={this.state.users}
        />
    );
  }

}
```

and

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  render() {
    /* ... */
  }

}
```

As you might notice `<FooContainer />` has state while `<Foo />` doesn't. In most cases it's easy to render `<Foo />` but rendering `<FooContainer />` may cause problems (simple one is `compnentDidMount` will never run).

So you should mock props of `Foo` and render it.